# Javascript closure in a for loop: why is loop index i invisible?

Tags: javascript, closures

Suppose given a function (it's part of an object, don't worry)

```
makeClosures : function(arr, fn) {},
```

where the parameters are, first, an array e.g. `[1, 2, 3, 4]` and second, a function (call it doSomeStuff) which squares a given number

`var doSomeStuff = function (x) { return x * x; }`

`makeClosures` is supposed to return an array same size as `arr`, where each element contains a reference to a function that basically calls `doSomeStuff`.

So here's my implementation:

```
makeClosures : function(arr, fn) {
  var funcs = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var f = function() {
      return fn(arr[i]);
    };

    funcs.push(f);
  }

  return funcs;
},
```

and **the question is**:

When I run my program, the return value of `f` is `NaN`. I tried with actual numbers (`return fn[1]`, `return fn(arr[0])`) then it worked, which means the problem is on `arr[i]` (undefined?). I suspect the inner function `f` doesn't see the loop index `i`. Why?

Comment: In JavaScript, lexical scoping happens at the function level. All of your functions constructed in the loop **share the same variable "i"**. At the end of the loop, what's the value of "i"?  Right: `arr.length`.  What's the value of `arr[arr.length]`?

Comment: What Pointy said. Create a function generator, passing in the current value of `i`, instead.

Comment: This question has been answered soooo many times...Search on SO you'll find the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pointy's comment:

"In JavaScript, lexical scoping happens at the function level. All of your functions constructed in the loop share the same variable "i". At the end of the loop, what's the value of "i"? Right: arr.length. What's the value of arr[arr.length]?"

The returned functions are executed after the loop iteration, and var i is still in scope with the value of array.length, which is out of bounds of the array.

Also, you should declare f outside of the for loop, scopes are created at the function level, not inside loops, so you are declaring f when it already exists each iteration of the loop.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure weather this will help, but this is what I tried and worked.

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4]
var fn = function (x) { return x * x; }

function makeClosures(arr, fn) {
    var funcs = [];   

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {     

        var f =  fn(arr[i]);       

        funcs.push(f);
    }

    return funcs;
}

myarr = makeClosures(arr, fn);

for (var j = 0; j < myarr.length; j++) {
    alert(arr[j] + ' square is : ' + myarr[j]);
}
```

Comment: please note that `funcs` should contain the reference to functions instead of their return values. I've worked out my solution though, thanks for the help.

Comment: This is wrong because you create an array of values, not functions. No closures in sight!